# Inequality for $p\geq 2$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

Let $p\geq 2$ and $s\in(1,2)$. Then 
$$
T=\frac{s^{p-1}+s^{p-2}+\cdot+2}{4^{p-1}}\leq 1.
$$
I was trying in the following way:
$$
T=\frac{(s-1)(s^{p-1}+s^{p-2}+\cdots+2)}{4^{p-1}(s-1)}=\frac{s^p+s-2}{4^{p-1}(s-1)}\leq\frac{2^p}{4^{p-1}(s-1)},
$$
where in the last inequality we have used the fact that $s\in(1,2)$.
After this unable to proceed. Can somebody please help.

Thanks.

Comment: What does $s^{p-1} + s^{p-2} + \cdot + 2$ mean?

Comment: Lets suppose p be a natural number first. Then how to prove it. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I can't prove something if I don't even know what it means. Can you please clarify what the expression means explicitly first?

Comment: Its a polynomial is $s$ for a fixed $p$ assume. where $p$ is a natural number.

Comment: Do you mean $s^{p-1} + s^{p-2} + \cdots +s^1 +  2$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your attempt, I assume that, for $p\ge 2$ and $s\in(1,2)$, you want to prove

$$T=\frac{(s^{p-1}+s^{p-2}+\cdots+s)+2}{4^{p-1}}\leq 1.$$

This can be done as follows:

$$T=\frac{(s^{p-1}+s^{p-2}+\cdots+s)+1}{4^{p-1}}<\frac{(2^{p-1}+2^{p-2}+\cdots+2)+2}{4^{p-1}}=\frac{\frac{2^p-2}{2-1}+2}{4^{p-1}}=\frac{2^p}{2^{2p-2}}=\frac{4}{2^p}\le 1$$

where the last step follows from $p\ge 2$.